# Changing PowerPivot model lanaguage

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have an Excel file that was created in the following environment:

- OS Language - English
- OS Locale - Russian
- OS Formats - Russian
- Excel Editing and Display language - English

This file uses PowerPivot where one of the calculated columns uses the formula `=FORMAT([SomeDate],"mmm")` that retunes short month names.

Now I open this file in the following environment:

- OS Language - English
- OS Locale - English
- OS Formats - English
- Excel Editing and Display language - English

but the column with `FORMAT` function still populated with Russian month names (i.e. `янв, фев, мар...` instead of `jan, feb, mar...`).

What I noticed is that in PowerPivot settings model language is set to Russian, but I have no idea how to change it.
[image: PowerPivot Options]

Is there a way to change model language or at least force `FORMAT` function to use current user locale?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start a new workbook after you made the above changes; otherwise, it will just stick to the language initially used in the model. You can export your stuff to the new workbook.

All the best
Robert Martin
Excel MVP

Comment: What do you mean by "You can export your stuff to the new workbook."? Does this mean that there is a way to transfer datasources and PowerPivot model to another workbook programmatically or I have to recreate everything manually in a new workbook?